# Is there a way to use a different account with YouTube?

Tags: google-account, youtube

I'm having problem using YouTube. I use different Gmail accounts for email and YouTube and I would like them to be separated.

Is there a way to tell YouTube to use a different account from the "system" one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, add both your account to Settings > Account, then you can choose which account to sign in to on the YouTube app.

1. Make sure to sign out first

   [image: Sign out]
2. Swipe left, and tap on Sign In

   [image: Sign in]
3. You should be presented with an account chooser

   [image: Chose account]

Comment: So I added the new account but on the youtube app I don't see the option to switch. It keeps logging in with my old account

Comment: @dierre: I've added some screenshots, what YouTube app version are you using? Very old version does not support multiple account, IIRC. These screenshots are from 4.4.11, the latest available on Google Play at the moment.

Comment: ok so, the thing now is that when I click login I just got an error "Cannot perform this action". Really weird stuff. BTW I'll accept it. Would you like to start a chat to help me solving the problem?

Comment: @dierre: try clearing the cache?

Comment: @LieRyan, you really shouldn't use blur on your screenshots. Instead, completely color over them. There are algorithms that can de-blur information, and in your case, I can see with my own eyes your two email addresses (if i squint, or if I adjust brightness and contrast in an image editor).

Comment: @Lie: Could you reduce the size of those images. They're huge.

Comment: @LieRyan: so this is weird. I just downgraded my version of the app on my Nexus 7 and finally it asked with which account to log in.

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly on the latest version as of today (5.0.21). Had to clear cache and restart YouTube for it to work. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I have YouTube app version 5.3.32 and the only way I could change accounts was to clear the data from Settings > Apps > YouTube and when launching the app again it asked which account I wanted to use.

Answer (score 0):

Log-in to Youtube with your other account and then add it to Google account. So Next time  you can choose either one from Gmail (there is option to switch accounts in Gmail).

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot add an account to the YouTube app and we are forced to use one account. I really do not understand why they haven't added that yet...

Answer (score 0):

Since some previous versions, you can add new account directly from YouTube app (as with other Google apps).

1. Open the drawer menu by tapping the 3 horizontal bars on the top-left (or swipe from left edge to the right)
2. Tap the current user/name on the top
3. Tap **Add account**.
4. You'll be redirected to add account wizard, follow the instruction.
5. After that, you can select the account you want to be logged-in from YouTube app directly.

Reference: [YouTube Android App basics](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3227660) (tested on version 10.18.55)